# Tool for creating UML

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, uml, tool-uml

I have a general question about UML.
Do you know about a tool (free) that diagram all the connections (aggregate) and inheritance that are in a program.

I want a combination of static UML + the aggregation between all objects (if exists).

I am working on C#, VS2005 tool and have at home 2008 tool

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VisualStudio 2010 has some kind of pack for that: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460723.aspx)

I've been using ArgoUML: http://argouml.tigris.org/

Answer (score 1):

you can try Astah Community, it's very easy to use.
[Astah Net](http://www.astah.net)

Answer (score 0):

Though there is limited/no support for Visual Studios 2005 or 2008 Visual Studio 2010 includes a [visualization and modelling pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx). As well as this visual Paradigm offers a free [community version](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp?edition=ce) of its software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Edraw** for creating and linking of static UML + the aggregation between all objects..